# How do you store each value separately using comma then they store into separate array?

Tags: java, arrays, delimiter, filereader

A simple data file which contains

```
1908,Souths,Easts,Souths,Cumberland,Y,14,12,4000
1909,Souths,Balmain,Souths,Wests,N
```

Each line represents a season of premiership and has the following format: year, premiers, runners up, minor premiers, wooden spooners, Grand Final held, winning score,
losing score, crowd

I know how to store a data into an array and use the delimiter, but I am not exactly sure how to store EACH data item by a comma into separate arrays? Some suggestions and what particular code to be used would be nice.

UPDATE:
I just added the code but it still didn't work. Here's the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GrandFinal {
    public static Scanner file;
    public static String[] array = new String[1000];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File myfile = new File("NRLdata.txt");
        file = new Scanner (myfile);
        Scanner s = file.useDelimiter(",");
        int i = 0;
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            i++;
            array[i] = s.next();
        }

        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
            if(array[j] == null)
                ;
            else if(array[j].contains("Y"))
                System.out.println(array[j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or perhaps store each line into array, for example array[0] = {1908,Souths,Easts,Souths,Cumberland,Y,14,12,4000}

Comment: I think I have an answer that can help, but I just want to clarify what it is that you want to do. You want to take each line from the file, and take each part of data from that line and put them into seperate arrays?

So, you want an array of years, an array of premiers, an array or runner ups etc?

And will each line have the same 9 bits of data?

Comment: This is Australian football (aka Rugby), right? G'day mate.

Comment: Yes you're right, Ben. I need to know how to do that.

Comment: Haha yes it is Australian football, Vikingsteve. I'm a big fan of Roosters :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working around a bit, I have come up with following code:

```
private static File file;
private static BufferedReader counterReader = null;
private static BufferedReader fileReader = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        file = new File("C:\\Users\\rohitd\\Desktop\\NRLdata.txt");
        counterReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int numberOfLine = 0;
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = counterReader.readLine()) != null) {
                numberOfLine++;
            }

            String[][] storeAnswer = new String[9][numberOfLine];
            int counter = 0;

            fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] temp = line.split(",");
                for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
                    storeAnswer[j][counter] = temp[j];
                    System.out.println(storeAnswer[j][counter]);
                }
                counter++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read file");
    }
}
```

I have added `counterReader` and `fileReader`; which are used for counting number of lines and then reading the actual lines. The `storeAnswer` 2d array contains the information you need.

I hope the answer is better now.

Comment: @Shuvo0o: (YourLine) is just a place holder. I was intending to show you the place where your line should be. I'll clean it up and post the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but that's a bit of messed up or maybe I'm confused with your code. I'll post the updated code without Linked List but when I ran the program it showed "Y Y Y Y Y Y..." that's not what I expected. What I expect is to display a full of list with "Y" as being yes to Grand Final held.

Comment: @Shuvo0o: my answer reads all lines in a file and puts every parameter separated by a comma into its separate array for e.x. all years will be available in `storeAnswer[0][]` all premiers will be in `storeAnswer[1][]` and so on (like Ben Green explained and you agreed). If you were to process any specific details say only _Grand Final held, winning score, losing score, crowd_ then read `storeAnswer[][]` and extract what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Use `ArrayList`. Its *dynamic* and *convenient*.

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList();
    String line = "";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("NRLdata.txt"));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            al.add(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(al.get(i));
    }
```

**What does not work in your case ?**

Because your `season` array is empty. You need to define the length, for ex:

```
private static String[] season = new String[5];
```

This is not right because you don't know how many lines you are going to store. Which is why I suggested you to Use `ArrayList`.

Comment: This code works well but we weren't taught to use Linked List so we have to use the regular array.

Comment: How do you select the specific data? For example, I want to display a list of premiers that held Grand Final, which says Y or N in the lines.

Comment: In other words, I want to display all the list of the data after the 5th comma?

Comment: Alright, if you want to use array then loop through text lines and count number of lines and then create array.

Comment: To check **Y** or **N**, do this: `line.split(",")[5].compareToIgnoreCase("Y")` or `line.split(",")[5].compareToIgnoreCase("N")`